# Select boxes in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Ask this question I have searched and read the form_helpers guide.

I'm create a controller like a job board.
In form the user can choose how much he would pay and by what (hour, day, contract).

So my form look like this

```
# _form.html.erb

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pay, "Pay" %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :pay, required: true %>
  </div>
```

And show

```
# show.html.erb

<%= @thecontroller.pay %> / xxx
```

Instead of "/ xxx" I want show the user choice.
In form, I want a list with 3 entry "Hour", "Day" and "contract"

I tested with something like that but I don't understant

```
  <select name="city_id" id="city_id">
    <option value="1">Lisbon</option>
    <option value="2">Madrid</option>
    <option value="12">Berlin</option>
  </select>
```

I need to create an another column ?
I need to create a helper or other code besides form ?

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `select` method.  The second argument is an array of arrays, the elements being first the value to display, and second the value to return.

```
<%= f.select :pay, [['Hour', 1], ['Day' , 2], ['Contract', 3]], required: true %>
```

Create a helper method for the `show` page..

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :show_pay

  def show_pay(n)
    %w(x Hour Day Contract)[n]
  end
end
```

And in your view you can do...

```
<%= show_pay(@thecontroller.pay) %> / xxx
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested and it don't work. First my number field returns to zero, second, the f.select selection is not saved.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's a number field!  Is it 1 for hours, 2 for days, 3 for contract?  I've modified my answer assuming so, but you can change the returned numbers as you see fit.

Comment: My number_field is a integer column. In form, the user choose how much he pay for a contract. So in form he select a contract and the pay and contract appear in the show page. Your understand? how much (integer) / the contract (hour, day, contract). The probleme now, when I choose Day, 2 appear in the number_field to. Maybe I need to create a new column in database for the contract?

Comment: It's working thank you (I have create an another column) but now I see 1, 2, or 3 in the show page and not the name.

Comment: You could do something like this on the show page `<%= %w(x Hour Day Contract)[@thecontroller.pay] %> / xxx` but I'm beginning to think what you really need is an `enum` ... except your value is not model backed.  But anyway, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have juste remove the number and it's working with name <%= f.select :pay, [['Hour'], ['Day'], ['Contract']], required: true %>